# Create HTML tables in WordPress without Plugin or Code

Tags: php, wordpress

I want my website users to be able to create tables without using codes or plugin.

Preferably by writing a function in theme's function.php.

Example:
if the user enters

```
[table 4]
c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6
[end table]
```

i want the digit `4` inside the table tag to represent the number of columns in the table. and each coma indicates the end of each cell.

I have tried a replace function in the functions.php of the theme. It helped me but for that the user have to write the code as below, which is not ideal.

```
[table]
[row]
[cell] c1 [/cell]
[cell] c2 [/cell]
[cell] c3 [/cell]
[cell] c4 [/cell]
[/row]
[row]
[cell] c5 [/cell]
[cell] c6 [/cell]
[/row]
[end table]
```

Comment: Well, you could easily write your shortcode to achieve that. What have you already tried? Also, that's not how shortcode attributes work in Wordpress; you'd need to specify something like: `[table cols="4"]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using Shortcodes inside of Wordpress. Adding them is relatively straightforward (please see [the docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)). A basic working example of creating this shortcode inside of your theme's `functions.php` is as follows:

```
function _my_theme_sc_table( $atts, $content )
{
    // Normalise the attributes:
    $a = shortcode_atts(array(
        'cols' => 4
    ), $atts);

    // Now extract the content (will be a CSV of items):
    $cells = explode(',', $content);
    $numCells = count($cells);
    $rows  = ceil( $numCells / $a['cols'] );

    $html = '<table>';
    $html.= '    <tbody>';

    for( $r = 0; $r < $rows; $r++ )
    {
        $html.= '    <tr>';

        for( $c = 0; $c < $a['cols']; $c++ )
        {
            $index = ($r * $a['cols']) + $c;
            $html.= '<td>'.( ($index < $numCells) ? trim($cells[$index]) : '' ).'</td>';
        }

        $html.= '   </tr>';
    }

    $html.= '    </tbody>';
    $html.= '</table>';

    return $html;

}   
add_shortcode( 'table', '_my_theme_sc_table' );
```

Usage is as follows:

```
[table cols="4"]c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6[/table]
```